# Xamarin MonoDroid Hide Status and NavigationBar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

In MonoDroid, how can i hide Navigation and Status Bar completely on a certain action?

So far i tried these lines of codes but without good results.

What i want is to prevent the user from switching out of the application.

```
Window.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
View.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Hidden;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am able to hide the status bar but not the navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); // hide the status bar
this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);  // Show the status bar
```

Comment: it helped me but made me confuse at first :D . maybe you have to change the comments :) //to show means to remove status bar. //to hide means to show status bar again

Answer (score 1):

The following link should help you
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/navigation_bar/